# Novo dataframe condicionado - python

Tags: python

podem me ajudar?
Como criar um novo DataFrame no lugar do código `print('ok')` da função abaixo?
Incluindo a coluna da empresa e colocando apenas a última linha nessa nova tabela se a condição for satisfeita.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf    

lista = ['LOGN3.SA','VITT3.SA','NEOE3.SA','SAPR4.SA']
for i in lista:
  base = yf.download(i,period='1y', progress=False,show_errors=False).reset_index(drop=False)
  base['Ticker'] = i
  
  vol = base['Volume'].tail(1).item()
  
  if vol >= 10000:
    #Novo df com os dados da ultima linha dos aprovados
    print('ok')
  else:
    continue
```

A expectativa é que fique igual a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço quem poder me ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um dataframe fora do for e ir adicionando o resultado a ele:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf    

lista = ['LOGN3.SA','VITT3.SA','NEOE3.SA','SAPR4.SA']
novo_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in lista:
    base = yf.download(i, period='1y', progress=False, show_errors=False).reset_index(drop=False)
    base['Ticker'] = i

    if base['Volume'].tail(1).item() >= 10000:
        novo_df = novo_df.append(base.tail(1),ignore_index=True)

display(novo_df)
```

| Date | Open | High | Low | Close | Adj Close | Volume | Ticker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-11 | 22.719999313354492 | 22.739999771118164 | 22.350000381469727 | 22.43000030517578 | 22.43000030517578 | 534200 | LOGN3.SA |
| 2021-10-11 | 9.40999984741211 | 9.479999542236328 | 9.359999656677246 | 9.390000343322754 | 9.390000343322754 | 15900 | VITT3.SA |
| 2021-10-11 | 15.600000381469727 | 15.699999809265137 | 15.420000076293945 | 15.649999618530273 | 15.649999618530273 | 367900 | NEOE3.SA |
| 2021-10-11 | 3.9200000762939453 | 3.950000047683716 | 3.880000114440918 | 3.930000066757202 | 3.930000066757202 | 2086700 | SAPR4.SA |